# How could I prove that $x^2+1$ and $x^4+1$ are irreductible over $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

How could I prove that $x^2+1$ and $x^4+1$ are irreductible over $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$?

**Theorem :** Let $A$ an integral domain and $I$ a proper ideal of $A$. If $f(x) \not \equiv a(x)b(x) (\mod I)$ for any polynomials $a(x)$, $b(x)$ $\in A[x]$ of degree $\in [1, \deg(f))$, then $f(x)$ is irreductible in $A[x]$

I think I have to use this theorem, but I am not certain. Is anyone could help me at this point?

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy, but I think these are reducible, at least in $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$. You can factor them into linear terms.

Comment: They first is not irreducible over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Comment: Neither of those polynomials are irreducible in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb 2Z$. A good first step before checking irreducibility is to see whether the polynomials have roots! In your case there are only finitely ($2$ and $3$ respectively) many candidates to check.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$? I would like to  factorise $x^8-1$ in product of irreductibles in the rings $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$? The problem is I really don't how to start.

Comment: If you don't know how to start you can SEARCH for similar questions. Either here or in your lecture notes/textbook. You SHOULD NOT ASK THE SAME QUESTION MANY TIMES:

Answer (score 2):

.$x^2+1=x^2+1^2=(x+1)^2$ in $2\mathbb{Z}$

$x^4+1 = (x^2+x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$ in $3\mathbb{Z}$

Neither is irreducible mod it's respective field. In fact, $x^4+1$ is reducible mod $n\mathbb{Z}$ for every $n$!